# Pass CF7 form data to plugin

Tags: plugin-development, api

I would like to know if its possible to send CF7 form submission data to a plugin to process a payment using an API.

The workflow should be as below,

User fills in form on frontend (CF7 form) --> Submits the form --> Before mail is sent data is passed to plugin (plugin A) --> Plugin A Gets the data and processes payment (using payment info submitted) --> Returns data to functions.php --> Submits return data to another plugin (plugin B) --> Plugin B then stores the data in database --> returns true --> Mail is sent (via CF7)

I have looked at hooks but I am not sure if they work in that manner.

I have build the plugin so that it works with the Payment Gateway, however I am unable to find a way to actually pass the data from the CF7 form submission to the plugin.

Further Info --

I have built the plugin using OOP methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete answer would be a little complicated since *'plugin A'* and *'plugin B'* should be analized in-depth so check for available hooks and filters, but if I  understand you wrote your own plugin so you have full control on it.
That said, a starting point to get submitted data from CF7 is the following:

```
add_action("wpcf7_submit", "Stack_308450_forward_cf7", 10, 2);

function Stack_308450_forward_cf7($form, $result) {
    // var_dump($submission->status);
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ($result["status"] == "mail_sent") {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        Stack_308450_wpcf7_posted_data($posted_data);
    }
};
function Stack_308450_wpcf7_posted_data($posted_data){
    //do something here
}
```

I've personally implemented some functions on CF7 submission: in this case we're processing data after mail sent so you should indagate yourself if you find a more appropriate hook such as "wpcf7_before_send_mail":

```
function action_wpcf7_before_send_mail( $contact_form ) { 
  // var_dump($contact_form);
};

add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'action_wpcf7_before_send_mail', 10, 1 );
```

Consider also issue regarding validation on submission which are also involved in this process.

Here follows a
[List of available CF7 hooks»](http://hookr.io/plugins/contact-form-7/4.5.1/hooks/#index=a)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yup after some reading I think thats the way to go.. I wanted to try keep it simple and try create its own hook which maybe fired within the function I called within the hook wpcf7_before_send_mail.

Just thought it might be better to have the plugin I build not rely on CF7 directly, however dont think thats possible and might complicate things quite a bit.